# can't open source in xcode

Tags: xcode, github, outline

I'm trying to open the source [outline](https://github.com/Jigsaw-Code/outline-apps/tree/master/src/cordova/apple/xcode/ios)

but when loading it into xcode the following situation comes out, who knows what it can be connected with?[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mima0.png)

my course of action:

downloaded the entire repository from github,
opened the project folder with xcode
got the same situation

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.